# REST request through Actions and Triggers

Tags: actions

In Drupal, I can define a Advanced Action in `Administration>Actions` , but the available options do not have a `Send REST request` option, how do I achieve what I want?

In my case, I want my remote service to know about a new node is being created, so I need to send the nid to my service.

I've thought of one dirty hack though, which is to use `Redirect to URL` and send my request through URL:

[image]

My server will receive the data it needs(which is the nid), and redirect the user back to their content using [node:id].

But like I said, this is more of a hack, is there a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Rules HTTP Client](https://drupal.org/project/rules_http_client) module will suit you:

> This module adds an action wrapping of drupal_http_request to use
>   Rules for making http requests. It has many general uses, because the
>   Hypertext Transfer Protocol is the foundation of web data
>   communication.